# Are one-person company savings taxable in the Netherlands?

Tags: income-tax, savings, netherlands

In the Netherlands, personal wealth such as bank and savings accounts over a certain amount is subject to taxes (box 3).

If an entrepreneur (*eenmanzaak*, with or without officialy qualifying as *ondernemer* for the tax authorities) has a business bank account, do the "company" savings count towards the box 3 taxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it is not.**

As stated in [this website](https://www.ikgastarten.nl/financien/betaalmethoden/zakelijke-rekening/zakelijke-rekening-spaargeld-in-box-1-box-3) for entrepreneurs (in Dutch, translation and emphasis mine)

> **If you have the savings in a business account , this falls into box 1**. Here, the tax authorities do not calculate with a fictitious return, but with the actual return: The interest rate on savings is currently very low at most banks, between 0 , 01% and 0.10%.

So for the business account, the capital is not taxed as wealth based on the assumption of a return. The tax authorities tax on the real return (interest, currently very low) of this business bank account, as it does with any other revenue.